# Unbound field that is editable while DAC is read only

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to extend the CRActivity DAC with some unbound fields so that I can use them on form CR306030 but, the DAC is read-only on that page.  So, my extended, unbound fields appear to be read-only in the smart panel that I am using.  How can I get my unbound fields to take a value from the user that I can then use on my code?

Comment: @nilsw welcome to acumatica framework, the question is tagged as acumatica, and if you know that framework you will know what is a DAC there.

Answer (score 0):

Examine code of EPEventMaint graph (the graph of the CR306030 page). You'll probably need to customize CRActivity_RowSelected event, to allow user input data for your unbound fields. 
Also your smartpanel should have Enabled=true in aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm not following.  Since my fields are unbound, I extended the DAC so, I can get the CRActivity row and call selectedRow.GetExtension<>() to get to my fields but, not sure how to make them writable on the UI?  Do I do that by field or by the entire row?

Comment: Wording "DAC is readonly on this page" is incorrect. Either the page can be disabled in aspx (by setting Enabled=false, which I believe is not the case), or in the EPEventMaint::CRActivity_RowSelected() (or in some installed extension if any) all DAC attributes are made disabled by a call like that: PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CRActivity.createdByID>(cache, row, false); So, if you override and put PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CRActivity.YourAttribute>(cache, row, true) - you should be able to write it.